# Legend in Matlab Graph

Tags: matlab

I need to produce a X vs Y graph and make a distinction between positive class and negative class (indicated in original data infile). How do I produce a legend in such a graph? This is my code for the graph right now :

```
infile = fopen('ClassData1.txt','r');
data = textscan(infile,'%f %f %f');
parameters = [data{1} data{2}];
label = [data{3}];
h = ones(100,9);
g = ones(100,9);
score1= ones(1,9);
sc = 0;
figure
for i = 1:100
        if label(i)>0
            plot(parameters(i,1),parameters(i,2),'r*')
            hold on 
        else
            plot(parameters(i,1),parameters(i,2),'b*')
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are (more than) two ways to do this. Firstly, you can just use a single `plot` command and do the legend normally, by combining the plot definitions using logical indexing, or you can use the `DisplayName` property for each plot to give information about the legend.

```
% Some sample data
parameters=rand(100,2);
label=parameters(:,1)-0.5;

% Use logical indexing to replace the for loop and use a single plot command
figure(1)
plot(parameters(label>0,1),parameters(label>0,2),'r*',parameters(label<=0,1),parameters(label<=0,2),'b*')
legend('red','blue')

% Use DisplayName to set the legend entry for each plot, then show the legend using the names given
figure(2)
plot(parameters(label>0,1),parameters(label>0,2),'r*','DisplayName','Red')
hold on
plot(parameters(label<=0,1),parameters(label<=0,2),'b*','DisplayName','Blue')
hold off
legend('show')
```

Answer (score 1):

To show each line type only once, you have to keep the handles. Storing only one handle per class is sufficient.

```
h=nan(2,1)
for i = 1:100
    if label(i)>0
        h(1)=plot(parameters(i,1),parameters(i,2),'r*')
        hold on 
    else
        h(2)=plot(parameters(i,1),parameters(i,2),'b*')
    end
end
legend(h)
```